# I have Lubuntu Software Center instead of Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center

Some how my ubuntu 14.04 has lubuntu software center and I do not have ubuntu software center? I want it to be normal. How do I delete lubuntu software center and install the normal software center? Thank you

Comment: to close voters: this is not a bug; seems to me that this is a manual install of another software center.

Comment: @Rinzwind that's why I removed the 14.04 tag. That is misleading.

Comment: Although you *can* install "normal" Software Center, I don't think there are any great differences b/w the Lubuntu one and the Ubuntu one.

Answer (score 2):

To remove lUbuntu Software Center:

```
sudo apt-get purge lubuntu-software-center
```

If needed you can install Ubuntu Software Center with:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-software-center
```